# Reference request: associated graded algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, graded-rings, algebras

To every filtered algebra $A$ we can associate a graded algebra $\operatorname{gr} A$ (more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_algebra)). That graded algebra is usually a simpler object than the algebra we started with, and we can deduce some properties of $A$ from looking at $\operatorname{gr} A$.

For an example, if $\operatorname{gr} A$ is an integral domain, then $A$ is also an integral domain.

I was wondering if anyone knows a good reference where those relationships are collected. It would be great if they come with a proof, but I'll take just a list of statements too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of links available if you comb through this website, e.g.,

- [if $\bigcap R^n=0$ and the associated graded $\text{gr}(R)$ of a ring is a domain, then $R$ is a domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116276/relaxing-a-condition-to-prove-that-an-associated-graded-ring-is-a-domain-implies)
- a counterexample to [$R$ domain implies $\text{gr}(R)$ domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116154/does-r-a-domain-imply-operatornamegrr-is-a-domain?rq=1).

Here is a pretty good reference: [Zariskian Filtration by L. Huishi and F. van Oystaeyen](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780792341840).

Here is another (online version): [Commutative Algebra by Keerthi Madapusi](http://math.uchicago.edu/~keerthi/files/CA.pdf), begin on page 21.